# RadioButton event does not get triggered with ajax manager

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a asp radio button as below on my aspx page

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RdNew" GroupName="batchType" runat="server" Text="New Batch" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RdNew_CheckedChanged"></asp:RadioButton>
```

If I have the Ajax manager for this control, the OnCheckedChanged event does not get fired. Removing the control from ajax manager works fine. My ajax manager is as below

```
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RdNew">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RdNew" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="grdProjects" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this and converted my radio buttons to radiobuttonlist and it worked for me.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/postback-not-firing-for-radiobuttonlist